# Rolling Out Printer Drivers via GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Heres the scenario I am in.  I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 with the print server role installed.

I have installed the necessary printer drivers that I want to push out via GPO.  I went to start, devices and printers and clicked add a printer and setup the networked printer (Konica Minolta).  The printer is printing fine and being pushed out fine (via user, not computer). I setup the printers to push out via the printer management tool that comes when you install the print server service role.

Now here in lies the problem, when I make changes to the printing preferences on the server it is not replicating to all the computers that have this printer deployed.

I have tried rebooting the pcs to see if it needs to reinstall via GPO.

I have also uninstalled then reinstalled the printer via the GPO.

I have done a gpupdate/force and still no success.

Is it possible to do this? and if it is possible how do I get the settings to replicate to all the computers?

The printer is a Konica Minolta Bizhub c284 and the driver im not sure of, it should be the latest one, I downloaded it from Konica's website.

Thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with GPO and it's entirely driver-specific. You might want to update your question with the specific printer model(s) in question and the exact driver version.

Comment: Are you changing the default preferences? Changing the normal preferences on the server is literally doing just that - they aren't the preferences the user gets.

Comment: Dan, I should be, I will double check.

Comment: Dan, I did do it that way and things are still not changing for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't need to replace printer driver just because you changed the print preferences. What you should be able to do is to deploy the printer via Group Policy Preferences using the Replace method/option. That should delete and recreate the printer on each client, updating the print preferences in the process.

Comment: joeqwerty, can you explain how I can do this?  Id really appreciate it.

Comment: I guess the better question is, since I made these GPOs using the printer management, where do i find the printer inside the GPO that gets created?

Comment: You can see what GPO the printer is deployed with by viewing the Deployed Ptinters node under the Print Management console (under Server Roles|Print and Documents Services). You can then remove it from Deployed Printers and assign it using GPP.

Comment: Great, ill remove from the management console and redeploy your way.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: It worked for the most part, what i wanted to do was update a password in the minolta driver and it wont allow it.  Thats ok though.  I was able to change everything else I needed.